# PostgreSQL driver issue

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, driver

This question was already asked many times, nonetheless I didn't find any suitable answer.

In short: "No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/Ecole"

My code:

```
import java.sql.*;

public class Connect {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            System.out.println("Driver O.K.");

            String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/Ecole";
            String user = "postgres";
            String passwd = "root";

            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, passwd);
            System.out.println("Connexion effective !");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Stack error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at Connect.main(Connect.java:6)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I diagnosed that the problem is most likely from my program looking for the driver at the wrong place.
Here are the following reasons leading me to this conclusion:

Connection successful on IntelIJ (also successful on Datagrip)
[image]

Driver up to date on IntelIJ (also valid on Datagrip) and class name of driver correct as stated in my main
[image]

Database is active on pgAdmin
[image]

Datagrip is doing fine
[image]

As mentioned above, all this leads me to the conclusion that my program is most likely looking for the driver at the wrong place (correct me I am wrong).
So what ? What are we supposed to do from this situation ? Many thanks for your help.

Comment: How exactly, and from which tool, are you running the JVM? The fact remains that the JDBC driver is not on the class path, so you have to put it there.

Comment: If you get a `ClassNotFoundException`, then the driver is not on the runtime classpath. The screenshots you show are entirely irrelevant to this problem. The first two and the last screenshots show the config of the database tooling inside IntelliJ/Datagrip, which is not related to running a Java application that use a JDBC driver: you need to explicitly add the driver to your application dependencies. The other just shows that your database is up and running, which again has nothing to do with your Java application not having the driver on its runtime classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so indeed I had to add the .jar file to the dependencies.

To do that:

1. download the postgresql .jar file in the following link:
   https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html
2. put it somewhere in your computer, it is advised to put it in your jre/lib like below:
   C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib
3. put it on your run time classpath as below. (it took me a long time to sort it out so I put everything step by step).

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You should not put external libraries in your JRE install. That is the wrong place to store things (consider what might happen if you upgrade Java). Create a folder somewhere else (eg `C:\Development\libs` or whatever you like).